# Android - multiple EditText fields in window resize

Tags: android, android-layout

In one of my views, I have three `EditText` fields. The first two are single-line, and the third is multi-line. I'm using `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize".` however the third field collapses far too small in portrait mode when the IME comes up and it has focus.

Is there an option to set a minimum height that would force the window to scroll down to accommodate the third field?

I have tried setting `android:minHeight="20dip"` in the `xml` file, but this has no effect.

The `EditText` in question looks like:

```
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/msgreplyarea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px" 
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android:minHeight does work, but the parent view needs to be wrapped in a ScollView

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
  android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText 
          android:id="@+id/replyarea"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="top"
          android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="10px"
          android:minHeight="120dp"
          android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
          android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction" />
    </LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Android documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) might help you with this. Or you can use a quick fix:

```
<activity name="EditContactActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

OR

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: you'll notice in my question I specify that I'm already using that.